# How can I update redux store in react-admin?

Tags: react-admin

I want to access the state of a resource and change that state so the list can render accordingly, but i don't want to hit another API to do so.
Can we access the redux store in react-admin? How can we do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the redux store using the useSelector hook.

```
import {useSelector} from 'react-redux'

function myComponent() {
  const myReduxData = useSelector(path.to.your.redux.key)

  return <p>myReduxData</p>
}
```

To modify data in the redux store you would write a custom reducer. You can hook into many of the actions that are fired automatically by react-admin. https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Admin.html#customreducers

**Redux is an implementation detail**

Although I gave direction with the above, I would highly recommend not going about it this way. React-admin views redux as an implementation detail (see the bottom of this blog https://marmelab.com/blog/2020/04/27/react-admin-tutorials-custom-forms-related-records.html)

That means you should never update redux directly. A future version of react-admin could realistically replace redux with something else which would break your app.

**What's the Problem You're Trying to Solve?**

In most cases there is a better, more blessed way to update the global state. If you provide some details as to what exactly you're trying to do I could advise you of a direction to pursue.

Comment: Okay, Thanks for the quick reply.
The problem i'm facing is i want to make my application real time & for that i'm using Firebase SDK at client side i.e with react-admin which automatically sees any changes in the database. 
I'm able to get the changed data at react admin but I'm unable to update the react- admin redux-store states that is shown on the UI.(List)
I dont want to use ra-realtime for the same.

Comment: What dataProvider are you using? Did you build your own? Have you looked at react-admin-firebase (https://github.com/benwinding/react-admin-firebase) to see if it would handle your use case?